# How do I install Sugyan-Tensorflow-MNIST?

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, installation, tensorflow

I want to implement [Sugyan Tensorflow Mnist](http://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist) in my laptop .It is an implementation of number recognition system.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.I have all requirements installed from requirement.txt .

What all steps should I go through next?
How to use npm install?

After I execute npm install command in the terminal I get this warning.

```
 aniruddh@Aspire-5742Z:~/Desktop/tensorflow-mnist-master$ npm install

 > tensorflow-mnist@1.0.0 postinstall /home/aniruddh/Desktop/tensorflow-mnist-master
 > gulp

 [11:29:47] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/tensorflow-mnist-master/gulpfile.js
 [11:29:47] Starting 'build'...
 [11:29:48] Finished 'build' after 883 ms
 [11:29:48] Starting 'default'...
 [11:29:48] Finished 'default' after 27 μs
 npm WARN tensorflow-mnist@1.0.0 No repository field.
 aniruddh@Aspire-5742Z:~/Desktop/tensorflow-mnist-master$gunicorn main:app --log-file=-
 [2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
 [2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6108)
 [2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Using worker: sync
 [2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6111] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6111
```

And after this its just Stuck here.

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in my repository.

`npm install` is a command to generate `static/js/main.js`. Warning messages can be ignored.

If `static/js/main.js` has been created, just run `gunicorn main:app --log-file=-` command and access the localhost:8000 in your browser.

Comment: Thank u for replying 
How do i find out if static/js/main.js has been created .
After I run this 
gunicorn main:app --log-file=-

this appears but after this nothing seems to happen 

aniruddh@Aspire-5742Z:~/Desktop/tensorflow-mnist-master$ gunicorn main:app --log-file=-
[2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6108)
[2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6108] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-12-15 12:34:49 +0530] [6111] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6111 

added this in the question

Comment: It's not stuck, just the web server is running.
Do you understand? This is just a web application, not a library or software to install.
As written in the log message, while running the `gunicorn main:app --log-file=-` command you can use the same web application as https://tensorflow-mnist.herokuapp.com/ in the local environment (http://127.0.0.1:8000/).

Comment: Ok so the web server is running and its suppose to open tensorflow-mnist.herokuapp.com locally right ? But its not opening. how long will it take to open.

Comment: What browser are you using?
When you visit http://127.0.0.1:8000 with web server started with 'gunicorn` command, what will be displayed?

Comment: I am using Chrome and thank you its working now  after i enter  this in the url box http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I was previously using mozilla it was not working then now in chrome its working